# Retrieve request body in HTTP request handler, Playframework 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using Playframework 2.4.11 and Scala 2.11.12. I am logging user access include request body

I create a request handler following [ScalaHttpRequestHandlers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHttpRequestHandlers) and [ScalaHttpFilters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHttpFilters). but all I can get is just `RequestHeader`

reference to [JavaHttpRequestHandlers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaHttpRequestHandlers). It is so easy to get request body

Anyone can tell me how to get request body in request handler for scala? Thank you

**Update**

reference to [More-powerful-filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHttpFilters#More-powerful-filters)
the doc said

> Play provides a lower level filter API called EssentialFilter which gives you full access to the body of the request. This API allows you to wrap EssentialAction with another action.

But I can not find any clear way to retrieve the body from [EssentialAction](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/HttpApi#What-is-EssentialAction?)

**Final Update**

After research in one week. I gave up on the idea logging user access in request handler and I also found another way to do my task

Thank you everyone

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using? It is really hard to tell without it.